# Microservice archtecture data sharing/management

Tags: design-patterns, microservices

I'm aiming at developing enterprise application using microservice approach.  One of pressing question I have is how am I going to share distributed data among microservices.

[Microservices data sharing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyRWG.png)

from the image above the Customer and Order microservice both have customer details, though in Order microservice customer infos are striped to only required fields. I understand there is a way to maintain consistency of data across microservices using events.

**Questions**:

1. Is this model (refer image) practical/scalable?
2. If customer data
       spans across 10 microservices, does it mean if I have 800K customers
       then all 10 microservices will have 800K data
3. what is the best
           approach For large dataset which is shared across
           microservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microservices must be loosely coupled so that they can be developed and deployed independently, each microservice has its own goal and *raison d'être*, a microservice has a well defined and non-ambiguous API to access his data.

In your case if you have a `Customer microservice` it must manage all the data and operations about Customers, if you need some data about an specific customer in your `Order microservice` you have to use `Customer microservice` **through his API** to retrieve that data; `Order microservice` must not store any data about customer.

For example if you need in your `Order microservice` the John Doe data you have to use the `Customer microservice` to retrieve the data for the customer with id=22, [this diagram shows the idea behind my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk0Bg.png).

And solving your questions...

1. No, it isn't scalable because you have data redundancy.
2. No, only one microservice must manage the customer data, and the other microservices have to use it.
3. **It is better explain by a good known pattern** to solve this problem; the [Database per service pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
For example
I want to search (by name) all orders placed by john doe. How do I implement that feature in microservices pattern?  Or I want to have order by name feature on the list of orders.

Comment: You are welcome c:
If you want to search by name you can follow the next flow:
1.  Your `CustomerService` must provide an "endpoint" which returns a Customer entity when you send the Customer name.
2. You can use this Customer entity to obtain the Customer id.
3. Your `OrderService` must provide an "endpoint" which returns all orders placed by the customer when you send his customer id.
This is an easy solution, however, there are many solutions to this question like private APIs, inter-service comms protocols, etc.